# How to Push Parent element to the height of absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css

Here is my fiddle:

### JSFiddle

You can find the sources [here](https://jsfiddle.net/outlander/532f86wq/) in a JSFiddle.

### CSS

```
.container {
    overflow:hidden; 
    position:relative;
    height: 350px;
}
.container .article {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: red;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="article">
            <img src="img/5.jpg">
            <span>title goes here</span>
            <span>some informations goes here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
            <img src="https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/thumb/8/88/LibreOffice_MotifScatter_RGB.png/300px-LibreOffice_MotifScatter_RGB.png">
            <span>title goes here</span>
            <span>some informations goes here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
            <img src="https://c.s-microsoft.com/en-us/CMSImages/microsoft-design-practice-delight.png?version=0c2ab83d-b515-9006-7c34-bf5021ffb656">
            <span>title goes here</span>
            <span>some informations goes here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
            <img src="https://www.verdadesign.com/assets/styles/square_300/public/thumbnails/image/custom-web-design-icon.png?itok=MS2LOkw6">
            <span>title goes here</span>
            <span>some informations goes here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
            <img src="http://www.suma-design.co.uk/images/graphic-design.jpg">
            <span>title goes here</span>
            <span>some informations goes here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
            <img src="http://www.redoinfotech.com/images/web_designing.jpg">
            <span>title goes here</span>
            <span>some informations goes here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In css section, I want to remove height:350px declaration and let my web browser pick the height of the image, but when I remove height, everything just disappear. I know this is because I'm using position:absolute but I need both position:absolute and removing the height:350px. So how can I achieve that?

**Note:** Using clearfix didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Removing height and overflow:hidden may be the solution

Comment: Yes but elements after div.article still have problems related to placement. for example if I put a div after closing div.article tag, this new div would not be visible to users because it's placement is behind all elements in the fiddle.

Comment: Should the multiple div.article appear as a stack?

Comment: May I ask you why you need every div.article to be position: absolute?

Comment: It's because I'm creating a slider and in that slider all div.articles should be positioned absolutely.